# Different clock time on Maas server and its nodes

Tags: maas

After I deployed Maas and Canonical Distribution of Openstack on a virtual environment (VMware ESXi), I found out that Maas server has a correct clock time while the nodes used for Openstack have different time. On VMware the NTP server is set with ntp.ubuntu.com.

[image]

[image]

From juju status I saw the container ntpmaster/0 and its ntp.conf is so configurated:

```
ubuntu@juju-eba318-3-lxd-1:~$ more /etc/ntp.conf
# juju generated ntp configuration
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift
statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable
restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery


restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1
# SERVERS


# LOCAL time source
server 127.127.1.0
fudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 5

# PEERS
```

why different clock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue, and didn't figure out any "elegant" or "built-in" solution. So I just did a workaround:

On the file `/etc/maas/preseeds/curtin_userdata`, right after the lines:

```
late_commands:
maas: [wget, '--no-proxy', {{node_disable_pxe_url|escape.json}}, '--post-data', {{node_disable_pxe_data|escape.json}}, '-O', '/dev/null']
```

Add something like:

```
late_commands:
maas: [wget, '--no-proxy', {{node_disable_pxe_url|escape.json}}, '--post-data', {{node_disable_pxe_data|escape.json}}, '-O', '/dev/null']
setup_timezone_01: ["curtin", "in-target", "--", "sh", "-c", "rm /etc/localtime && ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Berlin /etc/localtime"]
```

... and adjust that `Europe/Berlin` to 'Europe/Rome` or wherever your controller is running on.

This way, maas will set (hardcode) the timezone into the target machine during the installation process.

Once again, probably not the best solution, but it does the job for me.

Comment: that solution works also on my situation. thanks. I hope someone  correct that on MAAS.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the timezone settings?

e.g.

```
$ ls -l /etc/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Jun 28 12:37 /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC
$ cat /etc/timezone
Etc/UTC
```

If the configured timezone is different, you will get a different time.

Comment: here the result of that you said me https://pasteboard.co/2YtBjTit6.png